# how to convert from str.substring(0, i) into str.charAt()? (to make equal)

Tags: java, string

I tried in many times but don't know how to change str.substring(0,i) into str.charAt(i)
Please help
I tried to make a result as below but I struggle from str.substinrg(0,i) to str.charAt(i)
If i would like to make a result as below, at this point, how should i have to change it?

```
repeatFront("Chocolate", 4) → "ChocChoChC"
repeatFront("Chocolate", 3) → "ChoChC"
repeatFront("Ice Cream", 2) → "IcI"
```

below code is not successfully correct

```
public String repeatFront(String str, int n) {

    int i;
    String newStr;

    for(i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        newStr = Character.toString(str.charAt(n));
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: What are you even trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mano176 It appears to me like Jenny is trying to achieve the outputs shown in the first code block.

Comment: @MihirKekkar yeah, but with which process behind it? I don't really see a pattern behind those outputs so far

Comment: @Mano176 It's repeating the first k elements n times where k decrements from n to 1.

Comment: @Mano176 yes, as i shown first one, I would like to make the output like that by only using charAt function

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue if thats what you wanted, but the outputs are correct:

```
public static String repeatFront(String str, int n) {
    String newStr = "";

    for(int i = n; i > 0; i--) {
        for(int i2 = 0; i2 < i; i2++) {
            newStr = newStr + str.charAt(i2);
        } 
    } 

    return newStr;
}
```

Comment: I know you didn't ask for a code review, but I can't control myself. if `i-1` is replaced with `i`, the final append outside the loop is not necessary.

Comment: I edited it, should work i think but can't test it right now