# using loop instead of stream (java9)

Tags: java

I wonder how to change into for or while loop by using same format

```
public List<String> noZ(List<String> strings) {
  return strings.stream().filter(x -> !x.contains("z")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This is what I did so far, but I'm not getting the results yet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.stream().size(); i++) {
   string x;
   if (x.contains("z")) {
      String.valueOf(strings.stream().filter);
   }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: And what should the changed for loop do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasonable ways to rewrite this. One way:

```
public List<String> noZ(List<String> strings) {
    List<String> out = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String s : strings) {
        if (!s.contains("z")) {
            out.add(s);
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: what does it mean "s" in here? is it string or int ?

Comment: @JennyHong Yep, the above wont compile. `s` is a local variable for the loop (go google for-each loop in java), so it can't be used as return argument. I think the method is supposed to say `return out`

Comment: @GhostCat https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57939335/how-to-convert-from-str-substring0-i-into-str-charat-to-make-equal/57939735?noredirect=1#comment102295120_57939735 can you help for this link ?